# How to deal with frag rounds

Tags: battlefield-3

When I'm in the mood for some pure infantry goodness, I like to play Operation Metro. There are a variety of servers that offer some flavor of no explosives. One server I play on does not allow RPGs or grenades, but does allow frag rounds, claymores, and C4.

My question is: Does anyone have good ways to combat frag rounds without resorting to frag rounds? Take, for example, the left stairs at B (playing as RU). As soon as I go down the stairs, I'm usually hit multiple times by frag rounds. If I try to inch my way down, the blast effect gets me before I even see my enemy. Likewise, playing as US in this situation is no better, as frag rounds are hitting the back and side walls so even getting up into lockers is difficult.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to handle opponents like this, outside of getting a coordinated group to smoke/push (a response that is basically applicable to any situation)?

Comment: This is where I wish BF3 had flashbangs.

Comment: @Emerica. That actually would be kind of cool, though sadly I'm sure there would be people next to an ammo crate just flinging flashbangs every second. Maybe with a long reload time it could work, alas.

Comment: It would be just as devastating as sitting by an ammo box for smoke, or grenades, or explosives, or anything. I think with this new close combat DLC coming they should really consider it.

Comment: I don't really understand how you're getting killed so much by frag rounds. They have been nerfed hard by the last update. Now they take at least 4 rounds to kill you and they (seem to) no longer do any splash damage other than supression

Comment: @Earlz I don't know what situations you're playing in, but it's still very easy to spam the choke points in Metro and rack up a ton. On the server I'd been playing on, I'd routinely see people get 150-200 kills in a 2K ticket match, all of them coming from frag rounds. If there's multiple people frag rounding the same spot, it's not hard to get killed -- that or back off and play a safe game. There is definitely still splash damage -- I was trying it out myself and I was just aiming at the top of the wall by the metro stairs and racking up kills.

Comment: @Earlz If you don't believe me: http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/battlereport/show/28634115/1/355223965/ 230 kills with the Saiga. Trust me, he was using frag rounds. Not a hacker either, as I've seen various other people do it (including myself).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some recommendations to combat the dreaded frag-rounds:

- **Spread out!** Splash damage can easily wipe out an entire squad - which includes your medics.  Obviously if all of your medics are down, no one will get revived.
- **Use a VOIP system to communicate with your teammates.**  Voice communication will always be faster than typing your current situation or where your opponent is.  The faster your team knows where the opponent(s) with the frag-grounds is/are located, the faster  the target(s) can be suppressed and eliminated [in theory].  In my experience this also helps to notify the medic(s) around you, to let them you your location if you need a medic pack or a revive.  You can use any VOIP systems such as: Teamspeak, Ventrilo, BF3 VOIP built into the browser, etc.  If you don't know anyone in the server, don't worry.  Most servers are clan based and looking to expand.  Therefore, they will most likely post their VOIP server address.
- **Try not to repeat your paths toward the enemy.**  If you never switch up your approach when charging the enemy, they won't bother to nuke anywhere else.  I know on metro this can be limited, but there are some paths *less traveled:* From US spawn from B to A, try taking the exit on the left and try to flank.  From what I have seen, a well executed flank can turn the tide of the battle at any point with this method [ as most players sit on the far right to middle entrances of the metro[facing towards A]  A different example would be from A to B [being on RU] to blitz the locker room on the left side.  If you can hold locker room, it provides a great flank against your opponent(s).  There are many tactical approaches to attacking / defending in every map - not enough time to post them all.
- **Use Smoke!**  It really does work! If you blind your opponent(s), then will only have a general idea of where to fire for splash damage.  Smoke can provide the perfect cover to get the needed vantage &/ flanking positions.
- **Play on a server that restricts frag rounds.**  This is self explanatory, but a debatable option as DICE can technically justify you as a stats padder by not playing with the default restrictions on a ranked server.  If DICE thinks you are stats padding, they can reset your stats to 0s.
- **Strafe.**  Keep moving and try to stay away from walls when its possible.  A moving target is harder to hit - especially with the latest patch [see below]
- **Switch it up.**  Play a different kit that can help the players blitzing and in danger of the splash damage.  IE: Snipe! At longer distances (if applicable) , you will have the advantage over frag rounds.

Also note, with the latest patch that just came out, DICE nerfed the splash damage and power with the frag-rounds to make them more balanced.  It is now a lot harder to get that splash damage kill.

Comment: A good overview, though I do largely follow these steps already. However, as to "It is now a lot harder to get that splash damage kill," if only that were true. Maybe it's not as bad as it used to be, but I just finished a game where a player went 193-4 and almost all came from frag rounds. I thought maybe he was cheating but I found him and watched him and he basically just sat way back and spamming his DAO down into the stairs. I did the same thing for a few minutes to see if there was some aimbot aspect but I managed to start getting the same kills he was getting, alas.

Comment: I do think varying your route is probably the best option in any closed environment. On Metro, usually the escalators are not as bad as the stairs, for example.

Comment: One asepct worth noting. Have someone on your squad us the FLAK perk. The damage reduction is small, but sometimes it may make or break a push.

Comment: @AHungerArtist what system are you playing on?

Comment: @Foxtrot PC and I tend to only play 64 person servers.

Comment: @AHungerArtist you do have the option to search out the no rocket/rpg/mortar servers.  They usually include a rule against using/spamming frag rounds.  They almost always are full and our clan polices against spamming frag rounds on our servers.

Comment: @FoxTrot Yeah, thing is I like having mortars/C4/claymores allowed and most tend to go all or nothing. This one server allows those things and even bans USAS/Jackhammer, but leaves the other shotguns. DICE should give some way of telling what kind of ammo killed you, then they could kick for it. Alas. Accepting your answer for being thorough with your ideas.

Comment: Well I hope some of it helped.  It's a fine line on our servers.  C4, grenades, claymores are okay but we have a strict policy otherwise that has to be manually enforced.  Side note, my rep said you accepted then unaccepted?

Comment: Oops, thanks for telling me, I must have misclicked without noticing it.

Comment: @AHungerArtist No problem.  If you ever consider it, [which I don't know if I can promote my own clan on here but this still reflects towards your question] XGI has a few servers, 1 mainly that is metro, no rpg, no smaw, no mortar, and policed frag rounds.  You [and anyone else] are welcome to join us anytime.

Comment: I don't think DICE will reset you for not playing with the default settings, and playing within the rules of those servers.